# Json echoing empty data to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, json

After both sql commands are run, JSON should send an updated result to the AJAX script. Upon triggering, a spot opens in the page where the data should be populating, but nothing there. The PHP below is not creating any error messages and the data is updating to the db. I wish I had a more specific type of question but Im not finding the cause of the problem.

```
        $storyidr=$_POST['storyidr'];
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpasswd,$database_name) or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
         if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
           {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
           }
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_POST[storyidr]','$_POST[value]',now());"; 
        $sql .= "SELECT AVG(rank) AS avrank from ratings WHERE storyidr = $storyidr";
        if($mysqli->multi_query($sql))
        {   
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result())
        { 
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $avrank = $data['avrank'];
        if(is_null($avrank)){$avrank ="null";}
                if(!$mysqli)
                {
                      $arr = array ('status'=>'fail');
                      echo json_encode($arr);
                }
                else
                {


                      echo json_encode($avrank);
                }
                        exit;
        }
        }
```

AJAX

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
         $('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
             var ri = $(this);
     var value = ri.rateit('value');
             var storyidr = ri.data('storyidr');
              ri.rateit('readonly', true);
             $.ajax({
                 url: '../rate.php',
                 data: { storyidr: storyidr, value: value }, 
                 type: 'POST',
                 success: function (data) {
                     $('#response').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
                 },
                 error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                     $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                 }
             });
         });
    </script>
```

html

```
     <ul id="response"> 
     </ul>
```

Comment: What is the actual response from the server in the browser's debugging tools?  Are you sure there are no error messages anywhere?  Not even in the logs?

Comment: Just a guess as I have never used `multi_query` but you probably have to call `$mysqli->next_result()` to move the result pointer to the second query.

Comment: David, thank you. FF debugger is not picking up anything relevant.

Comment: Also, your code is wide open to sql injection. And by using multiquery it can be used to run any query a visitor wanted, including dropping tables and databases.

Comment: Jonathan thank you, do you know of an alternative to using Multi_query, I have the same concern

Comment: Johnathan, nice. question answered, needed  $mysqli->next_result(). thank you!

Comment: I would suggest running each query separately and using prepare/bind. That is the ONLY way to 100% make sure sql injection can't be run. Other than that, you can escape the variables before putting them into the queries.

Comment: Also, just an FYI. If you are talking with someone on SO, put @theirname in the message and they will get bumped that you replied. Once you type @ and start typing their name it will show their name in an autocomplete box and you can press tab to autocomplete.